# Getting React to work with Casper theme on Ghost with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ghost-blog

I am setting up a website in [Ghost](http://ghost.org) and trying to get React and Webpack up and running. I came across the following post:
https://medium.com/@tranvu/integrating-webpack-into-the-casper-theme-ghost-b68b49a073b4

and got Ghost default theme (Casper) running with Webpack after updating dependencies and webpack config.

What was surprising to me with this solution is that Webpack is not used to compile the handlebars templates. Apparently, the Ghost server is taking care of that.

I am currently stuck on how to add react components to the handlebar templates. Check the index.hbs and react component (QuoteComponent.js) files here:

https://bitbucket.org/bjornbrynjar/casper-react-webpack/

Is this the right approach, if so can you see what's missing, because the webpage gets rendered all scripts correctly linked but the following code doesn't work as it should:

```
const wrapper =  document.getElementById("quote_container");
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<QuoteContainer />, wrapper) : false;
```

Any idea or suggestion on how to proceed would be of great help!

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the original article you posted above. Just a note that the article was published a while ago so the latest version may require some modifications since API's has changed over time.

The Handlebars templates are rendered by Ghost, not by `webpack`. To use React, simply add your block where you are calling `ReactDOM.render()` in the `webpack.entry.js` file. From there, you can begin building out your component tree and splitting files if needed.

Comment: Thanks Vutran for explaining!  

I found the problem as your answer sent me in the right direction!

Was using the webpack.entry.js file to import the react components so that was not the problem.

When you confirmed this was the way to go, I took note of the output file, /dist/bundle.js, hadn’t been updated while I was testing this method and therefore it didn't work for me.
As soon as I replaced
`"dev": "webpack --open --mode development"`
with 
`devNotUpdatingWebpackOutputFile”: "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development`,
generating the file it works perfectly!